# How to fetch values with a MySQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to fetch all the records of First_Name, LastName, First Name Last Name in a mysql Query.

For example,

mytable looks like this:

```
rec Id      First Name     Last Name
1           Gnaniyar       Zubair
2           Frankyn        Albert
3           John           Mathew
4           Suhail         Ahmed
```

Output should be like this:

```
Gnaniyar Zubair, Frankyn Albert, John Mathew, Suhail Ahmed
```

Give me the SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this must the done in the query, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`, but unless you're grouping by something it's a pretty silly query and the concatenation should really be done on the client.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(FirstName + ' ' + LastName
                    ORDER BY FirstName, LastName
                    SEPARATOR ', ') AS Names
FROM People;
```

Comment: Thanks Blixt...

I am getting message that 1 row fetched...but nothing is displayed except "Blob"

Comment: Indeed, it is a type of BLOB (Binary Large OBject) because it can potentially get very long. It shows up as a BLOB because your client interface takes this into consideration and hides the field.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a matter of getting one row with all the records, but a matter of representation of data. Therefore, I suggest to take a simple SELECT query, take the records you need, then arrange them in the view layer as you like.

On the other hand, why do you need to solve this record concatenation at SQL level and not on view level?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get them in just one row, you're probably not using your database properly.

If you just want to join together the first and last names, that's easy:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(`First Name`, ' ', `Last Name`) FROM mytable
```

Comment: hi friends, Thanks for immediate response. this is right query. but all 4 records will display with this concatanation...i want to get all in single line.

your query will give output like,

Gnaniyar Zubair
Frankyn Albert,
John Mathew,
Suhail Ahmed

( total 4 records )

But i want to get only one record like,

Gnaniyar Zubair ,Frankyn Albert, John Mathew, Suhail Ahmed

Thanks in advance

- Gnaniyar Zubair

Comment: like I said, you're not using your database properly. thought it seems that the GROUP_CONCAT construct might help, as other have suggested.